# 複雑な条件の正規表現が生じました。この条件はどう書きますでしょうか？

Tags: 正規表現

文字の使い回しで複雑な正規表現に迫られました。
正規表現は一般テキストエディタです。

例題としては以下の場合です。

"　▼ｳｳｳｳ■ｳｳｳｳ★ｳｳｳｳ　ｳｳｳｳｳ"

ｳを8に変えたいですが、単純に全部置換するのではなく、以下の条件制限があります。

理想の結果
"　▼８８８８■８８８８★ｳｳｳｳ　ｳｳｳｳ"

解決したいこと

同じ行の文字列でこのうち、"ｳ"からすると、50文字以内前方に▼か、■が、ある場合については、ｳを８の数字に置換するが、★マークか、ひとつでも全角空白があった場合以降のｳｳｳｳについては、置換せずに無視するという正規表現です。

このときにたとえ５０文字以内前方に▼や■があったとしても全角空白スペースをまたいでいる前方の場合は反応しないという条件付きです。

"　▼　ｳｳｳｳｳｳｳｳ★ｳｳｳｳ　ｳｳｳｳｳ"
この場合は全角スペースをまたいでいるのでｳは置換せず反応しない

文字の使い回しで、マークの付いたところに応じて、同じ文字なのに置換したり、してはいけなかったのするため、このような設定をせざるをえない問題が生じました。

カタカナは例え事例のため適当ですが本質的にこれと同じ問題が起きてます。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「一般テキストエディタ」ではなく具体的なソフト名を挙げた方が良いと思います。仮に違うエディタでの回答があったとした場合、それを応用して自分の使っているエディタの場合に当てはめて適用するつもりなら話は別ですが。

Comment: エディタの正規表現で、とのことですが、awkやPerlなどのスクリプト言語で1文字ずつ走査していくやりかたの方がやりやすいような気もしますが、そっちの方向性での解決について検討の余地はありますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。勉強になりました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

コメントにもありますが、**正規表現エンジンによって持っている機能に差異がある**ため、回答に影響します。とりあえず一例ということで

JavaScriptにもある [`(?<=)` Positive Lookbehind](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%96%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%80%E6%98%8E) を使うと表現できます。これは現在の位置の手前が一定の条件を満たしているか判定を行うものです。

> 50文字以内前方に▼か、■が、ある場合

であれば **▼か■の後ろに任意の文字が49文字以下続く** として `(?<=[▼■].{0,49})`

> 50文字以内前方に▼か、■が、ある場合については、ｳを８の数字に置換するが、★マークか、ひとつでも全角空白があった場合以降のｳｳｳｳについては、置換せずに無視する

であれば **▼か■の後ろに★か全角空白以外の文字が49文字以下続く** として `(?<=[▼■][^　★]{0,49})`

ということで最終的な正規表現は `(?<=[▼■][^　★]{0,49})ｳ` となります。

Comment: 教えていただき、ありがとうございます。秀丸で動きましたがサクラエディタとEmEditor Professionalでは動作しませんでした。原因は何が考えられますでしょうか？

Comment: @senmai １行目は読まれましたでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。この問題でしたでしょうか？https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14346/%E6%AD%A3%E8%A6%8F%E8%A1%A8%E7%8F%BE%E3%81%AE%E5%BE%8C%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF-%E5%85%88%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AB%E9%87%8F%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A%E5%AD%90%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%88%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B

Comment: @senmai 「正規表現エンジンによって持っている機能に差異がある」という日本語が理解できないでしょうか？ 秀丸が採用している正規表現エンジンとサクラエディタやEmEditor Professtionalが採用している正規表現エンジンに差異があるというだけのことです。ですから hidezzz さんも「具体的なソフト名を挙げた方が良い」と提案しています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。理解致しました。

Comment: この正規表現は、EmEditorで使われる正規表現エンジン (Boost、Onigmo) では、先読み/後読み指定の `[▼■].{0,49}` の部分が**可変長**になるため、使用できません。